# What is the default window manager in 12.04?

Tags: window-manager

I don't know how to find the default window manager application name (executable file name and path). I need help to find the window manager.

Answer (score 5):

The default window manager is called compiz. Open a terminal and type

```
which compiz
```

to get the full path. Type

```
dpkg -l | grep compiz
```

to see in which packages it is replaced. Unlike what was suggested in a deleted comment, metacity is not responsible for Compiz window decoration, but a Compiz plugin called aptly "Decorations".

If, however, you log in using the "Unity 2D" option, you will be using a different window manager, called metacity.